# Failed at binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse)

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm using ITFoxTec Saml2 to connect to ADFS for authentication for my ASP.net core 3.1 MVC web application. I was able to get the SignIn page. After I submit the AD sign in information, I got error -  "IDX10214: Audience validation failed." from AssertionConsumerService.

My code for AssertionConsumerService is

```
 [Route("AssertionConsumerService")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
    {
        var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
        var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

        binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
        if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
        }
        binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);

        await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => Transform(claimsPrincipal).Result);

        var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
        var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

Does it have something to do with my Identity Provider? or do you have some advise? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Audience` is the relaying party (RP) `Issuer` that is your applications `Issuer`.

This is how the `Audience` is configured as the RP `Issuer` (in this example "itfoxtec-testwebappcore"):

- "itfoxtec-testwebappcore" is configured:
  https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/appsettings.json#L12
- and the configured value added in code:
  https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L37

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72801117/adfs-idx10214-audience-validation-failed

Comment: thanks Anders. I've confirmed the issuer is setup as expected. However when debug the value of saml2AuthnResponse, I found that the InResponseTo is null, Saml2SecurityToken is null, although the Status = Success. I'm suspecting the IdP didn't response with the correct information?

Comment: On top of my previous comment, I debugged more. I grabbed the SAMLResponse from the Chorome Network tracing, then use the SAML 2.0 tool (https://www.foxids.com/tools/Saml) to decode the response. The decoded content looks normal to me. <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_26284a5a-d803-472f-829b-119ca9365f1a" NotOnOrAfter="2022-06-30T15:53:17.802Z" Recipient="https://localhost:<nnnnn>/Identity/SAML/AssertionConsumerService" />

Comment: I think IdP did come back with a successful authentication response. But my web app keeps saying "IDX10214: Audience validation failed". I tried to login again 5 mins after, the app didn't require me to input my AD login/password again, which convinces me that the first SAML authentication was successful.

Comment: Did you get it to work. What Audience / Issuer has you configured and what issuer is returned in the SAML Authn Response?

Comment: hi Anders, after decoding, I took closer look at the audience, I always thought that it's matching the issuer, but I realize it's CASE-SENSITIVE!! (Sorry for shouting) but yeah, I literally just got it working after I changed the case of 2 letters in my issuer....  Thanks very much

Comment: Perfect :) Yes it is case sensitive.