# ADFS IDX10214: Audience validation failed

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have the same problem mentioned in [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777572/failed-at-binding-readsamlresponserequest-togenerichttprequest-saml2authnres), and I have configured and added the new code, but I still get the following message in the response:

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: 'IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.'

Edit:
After parsing the response xml I found out that when I set issuer="xyz", the response in the Audience tag is returning spn:xyz, I do not know from where I get the prefex "spn:". I am using Azure AD as my ADFS.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because old Microsoft SAML 2.0 code required an `Issuer` or `Audience` to be a valid URI, which is not required in the SAML 2.0 standard. From .NET Core Microsoft is aligned with the SAML 2.0 standard and accepts plain text strings.

I suppose you made it work by changing your `Audience`.